# Python Socket does not receive UDP packets

Tags: python, linux, sockets, ubuntu, udp

I am currently setting up a python socket for receiving UDP packets via ethernet and have problems with configuring the socket for obtaining data.
The ethernet adapter is configured with a fixed IP address. Using *tcpdump*, I am able to view the incoming UDP packets ([as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvlzk.png)) on port 4098, IP 192.168.33.30.

I am using the following example code for the socket:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.33.30"
UDP_PORT = 4098

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
           socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
     data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
     print("received message: %s" % data)
```

Unfortunately, there is no data return, even if the UDP packets are constantly send to the device. I am using a NVIDIA Jetson NX with Ubuntu 18.04.

So far I have checked the firewall and disabled it completely, but things did not change.

I am thankful for every advice on further troubleshooting!

Comment: Bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Are you sure the packets are received on the system? How do you check? For example by using tools like Wireshark on the receiving system? And what does the sender do, does it send to the correct host and port?

Comment: Or just specify the empty string `''` instead of UDP_IP.

Comment: Also make sure your firewall (iptables) is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Binding to `0.0.0.0` or `''` did not help either. I checked packets using tcpdump, screenshot is attached in link . Sender is configured to send to 192.168.33.30 on port 4098. Firewall is also disabled.

Comment: The code as shown works for me. First check if it works for you with client and server on the same system, for example using netcat (`nc -u 192.168.33.30 4098`). If this works then the problem is that the packets are blocked by a firewall. Note that tcpdump captures the packets before they are blocked by the local firewall, so seeing the packets there is no indicator that they actually reach the socket.

Comment: I was now able to find the problem: The sender has to be configured on a windows device, but I wanted to process the data on a Linux device. So I established the connection using the windows system and then plugged the ethernet to the Linux device, which resulted in routing problems because of the MAC address. Using *macchanger* on Linux helped me receiving the UDP packets. Thanks again for your kind help!